# unable to find new_post_path, and other template functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_post_path'
```

on my index page with a model setup of:

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :postcontent, :poster, :postname
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :username
  has_many :posts
end
```

My template for my index page is as follows:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Postname</th>
    <th>Postcontent</th>
    <th>Poster</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.postname %></td>
    <td><%= post.postcontent %></td>
    <td><%= post.poster %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

and the controller for this is:

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

as for routing, my `rake routes` output is:

```
    user_posts GET    /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
               POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
               PUT    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
               DELETE /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
         users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
          root        /                                        home#index
```

and my routing file is:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
```

It is notable however, I am getting similar errors to this on *all* other templates relating to `posts#*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `posts`as nested resource of `users`. You need to have a path like `new_user_post_path(@user)`.
Make sure you have a
 `@user` to pass this helper.

In you `index` action of `posts` controller fetch user like this.

```
@user = User.first
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `User` object in `Post`'s path
Something like that

```
@user or current_user
new_user_post_path(@user)
```

Comment: I'm a beginner when it comes to RoR, could you give me an example?

Comment: since post can be created using user so everytime we need to pass user's object to post controller or if you are using devise then you can get current_user object.